# My desktop Icons and files are showing full path after the name. How do I remove the path?

Tags: icons, directory, filename

For example: if folder is called Books, now it is displayed as Books/home/ivan/Desktop. All happened after trying to install different file manager than Nautilus. Very confusing and clattering.

Comment: which file manager are you using now? (what happened when you go to `help->about`?

Comment: Does pressing `CTRL + L` solve this issue?

Comment: That's strange should in the first instance it not be `/home/ivan/Desktop/Books`, did it create a `Books` directory too?

Comment: I am using Files 3.20.4 (also called Nautilus). CTR+L doesn't help.